# How much money did the RAND corporation receive from the U.S. government and its agencies?

Tags: united-states, government, think-tanks

> The top 50 think tanks in America, as ranked by the University of
> Pennsylvania’s Go To Think Tank Index, received over $1 billion from
> U.S. government and defense contractors. The top recipients of this
> funding were the RAND Corporation, the Center for a New American
> Security, and the New America Foundation, according to analysis by the
> Center for International Policy.

https://www.theamericanconservative.com/swamp-report-top-50-u-s-think-tanks-receive-over-1b-from-gov-defense-contractors/

I see the figure $1,029,100,000, but the website doesn't break it down per donor type, and defense contractors can be private organizations that have nothing to do with the government, so I was wondering how much money they received from the U.S. government including government agencies like the U.S. Department of Homeland Security. Is this figure made public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This chart showing the sources of the RAND Corporation's revenues, from [the RAND corporation's website](https://www.rand.org/about/how-we-are-funded.html), pretty much answers the question.